# Find records in a Extjs Store for which displayValue starts with a specific substring

Tags: regex, extjs, extjs-stores

I am trying to fetch records from ExtJS store which start with specific substring.

e.g. If I have a country store and if I have a string 'IN' then I want records of India and Indonesia from store.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is about a `combobox`, so that's the default behavior.

For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11r4

---

If you just want to filter a store, look at:

- [`filters`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-filters) config - Array of Filters for this store.
- [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-filter) method - Filters the data in the Store by one or more fields.
- [`filterBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-filterBy) method - Filters by a function.
- [`Ext.util.Filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter) - Represents a filter that can be applied to a MixedCollection.

Comment: Yep , this is related to combo but I want this logic for some other functionality. Thanks filterBy would do my work.